# Mails sent using javamail aren't found in the sent folder of Outlook

Tags: outlook, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using javamail for Sending mails using Office365 account. I couldn't find the sent mails in the sent folder of my outlook. Interestingly, I could find the mails in sent folder if I use EWS for sending mail. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, messages sent though Office 365 SMTP are not copied to the Sent Items folder.

That might change in the future.

Comment: If so, sent mails will not be stored in the SMTP server?

Comment: That is correct. SMTP protocol does not assume any persistent storage, even though a particular implementation is free to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for your responses :-) Interestingly, I have configured office365 in mail app in mac and send mails through it. I could find that gets reflected in outlook. Then MAC mail uses which protocol to send mails?

Comment: Most likely EWS. Or maybe REST. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-send-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: Mac mail, like most mail readers, probably explicitly copies the message to the "sent" folder, just like you can do with JavaMail.